# Retrofit2 Android Java

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Здраствуйте. Не как не могу вникнуть как отправлять изоброжения на сервер с помощью retrofit2. В данный мамент отправляю в строку base64 но этот подход мне не нравиться. Не могли показать пример?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например вот так:

```
Path path = Paths.get("path/to/file");
byte[] content= Files.readAllBytes(path);
RequestBody body = createRequestBody("application/octet-stream", content);

@POST
Call<ResponseBody> post(@Body RequestBody body, 
                        @Url String url);
```

Comment: А в интерфейси я первый раз вижу @url аргумент. Если убрать и сделать @POST("url") ничего не изменится правильно? И если мне нужно рядом json послать еще один аргумент ставить?

Comment: @user8978194, да. Можно просто @POST("url"). Тоже самое будет. Вот хороший туториал по Retrofit: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client